# How to copy templates directory to destination using yeoman?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

i have templates directory in yeoman that i want to copy to destination path with all the content it is throwing error that i have added to the question, is there better way to do achieve this task ?

index.js

```
'use strict';
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  prompting() {
    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(
      yosay(
        `Welcome to the epic ${chalk.red(
          "generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator"
        )} generator!`
      )
    );

    const prompts = [
      {
        type: "input",
        name: "name",
        message: "Your project name",
        // Defaults to the project's folder name if the input is skipped
        default: this.appname
      }
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then(props => {
      // To access props later use this.props.someAnswer;
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  // writing() {
  //   this.fs.copyTpl(
  //     this.templatePath("package.json"),
  //     this.destinationPath("package.json")
  //   );
  //   this.fs.copyTpl(
  //     this.templatePath("app"),
  //     this.destinationPath("src")
  //   );
  // }
  writing: function () {
    this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('app/templates'),
      this.destinationPath('app/templates')
    );
  }

  install() {
    this.installDependencies();
  }
};
```

Error

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist:
```

source directory path

```
generators/app/templates all the files are in templates that i want to copy to destination
```

Comment: having this same problem

Answer (score 1):

if your templates are in `generators/app/templates`, I think you need to change your template path to `templatePath('templates/NAME-OF-TEMPLATE.JS')`

the way i figured this out was by logging `__dirname` just before the `copyTpl` invocation.  Compare `__dirname` to the source it's looking for in the error and you should be able to figure it out.